# How to prevent generating a new commit sandwiched in the middle during a git rebase?

Tags: git

I have a branch like this `A->B`

I mistakenly added an extra string to the original string `Foo` and it became `Fooo` in commit A.

And I remove the `o` in commit B. (i.e. `Fooo -> Foo`)

The purpose of both `A` & `B` are just adding new files so I want to eliminate all the confusing changes on `Foo`

After removing extra `o` at commit `A`, I git commit --amend and get a new commit `A'`

Now I want to make the branch like this: `A'->B'`

Here is the step:

`git checkout B`

`git rebase -i A'`

A file shows and lets me to edit, such as something like : `pick:B`, I don't change anything.

I expect that I could edit the conflict, but after `git rebase --continue` the rebase finished immediately.

Finally I get a stupid result `A'->A''->B'`.

The commit `A''` add the extra `o` I removed at `A'`, then the `B'` removed it again.

How can I do to eliminate all the confusing changes on `Foo`?

---

I figure out how to do it simply.

The content of file shows after rebase is:
`pick:A`
`pick:B`

After removing the line `pick:A`, than I rebase it smoothly.

I think the solution for squashing A'' & B' also works.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Go to the original branch. Do an interactive rebase, do the squash command on the commit which should become part of the previous commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you still have:
`A' -> A'' -> B'`
what we need to do is combine `A''` and `B'` together. Once you do this, both the addition and removal of `'o'` will be in a single commit (say `B''`) and they will cancel each other out, i.e., they won't show up in a commit patch.

To accomplish this, you can do the following:

Execute:

```
git rebase -i A'
```

Now, you will get an editor with commits `A''` and `B'` listed. Change the `pick` beside `B'` to `squash`. Save and close the editor.

Next, git will open an editor where you can provide the commit message you want commit `B''` to have. Git will have the editor pre-filled with the messages of `A''` and `B'` in it, so you just have to remove the message of `A''` from it, save and exit the editor.

This should get you, `A'' -> B''` as you require.

---

I'm not sure exactly what went wrong in what you originally did, but you may have used checkout while you were in the middle of a rebase.
What I would do in your original situation would be:

1. Remove the removal of `'o'` from `B` first using a normal `git commit --amend`.
2. Use interactive rebase (`git rebase -i <parent of A'>`)
3. Change `pick` beside `A` to `edit`. Save and exit.
4. Now you will be at commit `A`. Remove the `'o'` from `A` using `git commit --amend`.
5. `git rebase --continue` to finish the rebase.